# x2go client on display2 with enabled alt tab setting (custom xserver setting)

Tags: shortcut-keys, x2go, x2goclient

I am using x2go Client.

I am able to see full screen on display2,

I am also able to change setting to enable alt+tab with custom xserver setting (-rootless -keyhook -notrayicon -clipboard).

Problem: I can't run both together (like using display2 full screen with alt+tab option enabled)